# Returning the middle value when giving the function 3 integer arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code is restarting the Python shell, and I cannot work out the errors of my code.

```
def middle(x,y,z):
    if x > y and x < y:
       return x
    elif y > x and y < z:
       return y
    elif z > x and z < y:
       return z
    else:
       return False

#Main Routine
middle(1,11,111)
```

Comment: There is no runtime or syntax error here. Your code is executed just fine and Python just exits. Did you mean to use `print middle(1, 11, 111)` perhaps?

Comment: Just a suggestion: You'd be better off raising a `ValueError` if `x == y or x == z or y == z`.  Because if you're calling it as `x = middle(0, 0, 1)` you're going to return `False`, but if you're evaluating the answer, `if x: ...` is going to act the same whether `x == 0` or `x == False`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Python can chain comparisons for you (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)), and you are missing several cases:

```
def middle(x, y, z):
    """Return the middle of the three input values."""
    if y < x < z or z < x < y:  # or min(y, z) < x < max(y, z)
       return x
    elif x < y < z or z < y < z:
       return y
    elif x < z < y or y < z < x:
       return z
    return False
```

In use:

```
>>> middle(1, 11, 111)
11
```

If you want to see results when running the script directly, you will have to be explicit about this; as [Martijn suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072926/returning-the-middle-value-when-giving-the-function-3-integer-arguments/30073077#comment48259670_30072926), you could `print middle(1, 11, 111)`. Otherwise the result will be evaluated, but not actually shown on-screen.

---

You can also simplify by *sorting* the inputs:

```
def middle(x, y, z):
    """Return the middle of the three input values."""
    x, y, z = sorted((x, y, z))
    return y if x < y < z else False
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do with this but your function looks weird to me

For example:

```
if x > y and x < y:
```

Will never be true

Also, if this function aims at returning the median of the three value it does not do this.

it would be more like

```
def middle (x, y, z):
  t = [x, y, z]
  t.sort()
  return t[1]
```

Hope this helped

Comment: This won't give the same result, e.g. `False` where `x == y`.

Comment: This is why I said "if this function aims at returning the median of the three value [...] it would de more like"
I assumed the function was not behaving as expected because the code doesn't look correct (dead code and strange behaviour)

If you want to return false if at least 2 values are equal you just have to add :
if x == y or y ==z or x == z:
  return False